# A Probability Problem in Manhattan Mobility Model

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Let's consider the Manhattan Grid Map and Manhattan Mobility Model:

Suppose there are $n$ users in a grid area with $r*r$ grids. Users' initial locations are randomly distributed. Users may walk between grids randomly, with 25% left, 25% right, and 50% up. Suppose there are $T$ rounds, and each user can walk through one grid per round. The edge effect is eliminated by considering that a user will rejoin the grid from the opposite side in the next round when he moves beyond the grid.

Each user $i$ is associated with a value $\sigma_i$. Suppose each grid $j$ is covered by a set of users $\mathcal{S}_{j,t}$ in $t^{th}$ round. A function is defined as follows:
$$f(\mathcal{S}_{j,t}) = \frac{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}_{j,t}} \sigma_i}{|\mathcal{S}_{j,t}|^2}$$

What is the expected value of $\sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j \in \mathcal{L}} f(\mathcal{S}_{j,t})$ (where $\mathcal{L}$ is the set of $r*r$ grids)?